# insert new section with UIButton (or Bar button) in Xcode using swift

Tags: swift, xcode, insert, tableview, sections

In Xcode (using swift) I have a tableView with 3 sections. I want the insert a new section when the user taps a button, with the title for the section being fed in from a textField (the textField is not in the tableView)

I am familiar with the `tableView.insertrow`(just pass in correct indexPath), but I don't know how to use `tableView.insertSection` (which requires an indexSet).

I'm using a 2d array to populate the table View.

```
var twoDArray = [
["apple", "banana", "pear"],
["carrot", "broccoli"],
["chicken", "beef"]
]
```

currently the titles for my headers are stored in a separate array:

```
var sections = ["Fruits", "Veggies", "Meats"]
```

How can I insert a new section with input from `textField.text` when the user taps the button using `tableView.insertSection` (ideally, I would like to do this without reloading the entire tableView)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to add a 4th section and animate the section insertion you could do something like this:

```
var twoDArray = [
["apple", "banana", "pear"],
["carrot", "broccoli"],
["chicken", "beef"]
]

var sections = ["Fruits", "Veggies", "Meats"]

//After user presses the button
sections.append("Candy")
twoDArray.append(["Chocolate", "Pure Sugar"])

self.tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sections.count - 1), with: .automatic)
```

You just need to make sure your datasource arrays are set prior to calling `insertSections` or you will crash with an error letting you know that your section insertion needs to match your source insertion.

Comment: You're awesome, thank you. One question: Why is it sections.count - 1 instead just sections.count?

Comment: @Nobadi Because arrays are zero-indexed.  The 4th element in an array has an index of 3.  If you used `sections.count` it would be out of bounds.